# Netbeans not forcing me to try catch when method throws an exception

Tags: java, netbeans, exception, try-catch

I'm using `Netbeans 8 IDE` and I just came to this odd situation. Let's say I've a method in a class that `throws` and `Exception` and when I call that method `Netbeans` does not enforce the `try catch`. Sometimes an `Exception` may occur and it is not catch.

Why isn't Netbeans enforcing the `try catch` method?

Here's an example:

```
public class MyMethodClass {

    public MyMethodClass() {}

    public void someMethod() throws NullPointerException {
        // do something

        if(something == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }

        // do something else
    }
}


public class MyClass {

    public MyClass() {
        MyMethodClass mmc = new MyMethodClass();

        // Here Netbeans does not force me to use a try catch, why?
        mmc.someMethod(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: RuntimeExceptions don't need to be handled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NullPointerException` is an unchecked exception, which means that you don't always need to catch it.  Unchecked exceptions are those which extend `RuntimeException` or `Error`.  The main purpose of these is for cases where there usually is no recovery; methods aren't required to declare unchecked exceptions either.  This is perfectly valid:

```
public void throwNPE() {
    throw new NullPointerException();
}
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html) is one of Oracle's statements on checked vs unchecked exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

`NullPointerException` is an unchecked exception (since it's a subclass of `RuntimeException`). You don't have to catch unchecked exceptions for the code to compile.

> [RuntimeException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) and its subclasses are unchecked exceptions. Unchecked exceptions do not need to be declared in a method or constructor's throws clause if they can be thrown by the execution of the method or constructor and propagate outside the method or constructor boundary

Answer (score 2):

Because `NullPointerException` is an unchecked exception.